# Expanded Letter Space Kerning Algorithm Not Working with French Accents

Tags: spacing, titles, algorithms, accents, kerning

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{scalefnt}


% Spaceout Algorithm

\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}


% Overlay Title

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \Huge
  \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{red!75!black}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.37pt}{\usebox1}}
\egroup}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
{\vstretch{2.25}{\mytitle{\textbf{\scalebox{0.8}{{NO ACCENTS (No Spaceout)}}}}}}
\vskip 15pt
{\vstretch{2.25}{\mytitle{\textbf{\scalebox{0.8}{\spaceout[3pt]{NO ACCENTS (w/ Spaceout)}}}}}}
\vskip 15pt
{\vstretch{1.85}{\mytitle{\textbf{\scalebox{0.8}{{Raison D'\^{E}tre (No Spaceout)}}}}}}
%{\vstretch{1.85}{\mytitle{\textbf{\scalebox{0.8}{\spaceout[3pt]{Raison D'\^{E}tre (w/ spaceout)}}}}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

So far, the algorithm works nicely.

However, when I uncomment the line `%{\vstretch{1.85}{\mytitle{\textbf{\scalebox{0.8}{\spaceout[3pt]{Raison D'\^{E}tre (w/ spaceout)}}}}}}` and run the code, I get an error.

It seems that the `\spaceout` algorithm I am using does not work when such accents are involved.

QUESTION: Can anyone tell me how I may be able to apply the `\spaceout` command when the title involves French accents?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not using `microtype` for letter spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside all the irrelevant things in the question, this boils down to the question why your loop doesn't work with `Raison d'\^Etre`.

Well, it doesn't because after having processed the apostrophe, the next token which is examined is `\^` and you get

```
\^\ifx\relax Etre...
```

It's obvious that trying an accent over `\ifx` is not a good idea.

Simple solution: use `microtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

Raison d'\^Etre

\textls{Raison d'\^Etre}

\textls[200]{Raison d'\^Etre}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you can do the coloring, boxing and scaling as you like.

If you want to go the hard way, you need to scan for accented letters and protect the whole thing in braces. *Caveat*: UTF-8 accented letters are not allowed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\theLetterSpace}{0.5pt}
\newcommand{\theWordSpace}{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceout}{O{\theLetterSpace}m}
 {
  \setlength{\LocalLetterSpace}{#1}
  \mlchristians_spaceout:n { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mlchristians_spaceout_text_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mlchristians_spaceout:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mlchristians_spaceout_text_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__mlchristians_spaceout_text_seq
   {
    \__mlchristians_spaceout_word:n { ##1 }
    \hspace{\theWordSpace}
   }
  \unskip
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mlchristians_spaceout_word:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{\^|\'|\`|\"}) ([^\{]) } { \{\1\2\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{\^|\'|\`|\"}) (\{.\}) } { \{\1\2\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 \kern \LocalLetterSpace } \unkern
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Raison~d'\^Etre

\spaceout{Raison d'\^Etre}

\spaceout[5pt]{Raison d'\^{E}tre}

\end{document}
```

[image]